# excel get max value for each day with corresponding time

Tags: excel

Can you guys help me finding a solution for this issue? here is an example

I have a set of intraday trading data (15 min data) in TXT. Data goes from 1997 to 2020.

```
Date,   Time,   Open,   High,   Low Close,  Volume, Max of Day, **??Time of day 
 Max reached??**    
9/11/1997   430 1082.25 1082.25 1079.75 1079.75 5   1082.25   ??        
9/11/1997   545 1079.25 1079.25 1079.25 1079.25 1   1082.25     
9/11/1997   800 1078.75 1078.75 1078    1078    5   1082.25     
9/11/1997   815 1078    1078.25 1077    1077    8   1082.25     
9/11/1997   830 1076.5  1077    1074.75 1074.75 25  1082.25     
9/11/1997   845 1074    1075.25 1073.5  1074.75 18  1082.25     
9/11/1997   900 1075.75 1076.25 1074.75 1075.75 14  1082.25
```

How can I ask excel to tell me at what time of each day we reached max and min for that day? I want the result in an additional column. For each row I want to know at what time we reached MAX for that day.

I am trying MATCH INDEX function but my brain does not cooperate....

With MAXIF I can get the max for each day. I am not able to get the corresponding time this extreme was reached.

Thx

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. .. If the data is in "A1:G9", like $A$1_Date,$B$1_Time,$C$1_Open,$D$1_High,$E$1_Low,$F$1_Close,$G$1_Volume, then index match formula will be `INDEX($B$2:$D$9,MATCH(MAX($D$2:$D$9),$D$2:$D$9,0),1)`

Comment: Thank you so much Naresh. But your function does not include the day in the calculation. I need max for each day and get correspondent time. Appreciate your help

Comment: There is a separate column for time. Also, I am not sure if that is 24 hour format time. It seems like 12 Hours format. It would be better if Date column includes time as well... OR .. You can apply the same formula to find the date and concatenate that with time.  Like `INDEX($A$2:$D$9,MATCH(MAX($D$2:$D$9),$D$2:$D$9,0),1)&INDEX($B$2:$D$9,MATCH(MAX($D$2:$D$9),$D$2:$D$9,0),1)` .. Result will be text and not date. Also, date is same in all cases

Comment: Time format is 24hr. Date should be not the same for all cases because for each day there is a new max. What I need is to know at what time that max was reached. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Open is in column C, the MAXIF (for Open) result is in G2, and time column is in column B2:B8, do :

```
=index(B2:B8,match(G2,C2:C8,0))
```

Hope it helps..